# how to cat mulitiple variables and store the value to another variable in shellscript

Tags: shell

i have a script to parse filename in a directory and tried to construct the full table names:

```
_keySpace=$(sed 's/CREATE KEYSPACE IF NOT EXISTS//I' cassandra/tables/keyspace_dev.cql|sed 's/CREATE KEYSPACE//I'|awk '{print $1}') => test_keyspace

for _dataFile in `ls cassandra/tables/data/*.csv`
do
  echo "${_dataFile}" => cassandra/tables/data/a.csv

  tableName= echo "${_dataFile}" | awk -F'[/.]' '{print $4}'
  echo "${tableName}" => a

  fullName="${_keySpace}.${tableName}"

  echo "$_keySpace.$tableName". => not working, only output test_keyspace.

done
```

how can i cat keySpace and tableName  to be like test_keyspace.a?

Comment: `echo "$_keySpace.$_tableName". => not working, only output test_keyspace.` Well your variable is called `tableName`, not `_tableName`.

Comment: oh, that's a typo, fixed it, still got the same result. not working

Comment: [Don't parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: Comments should be formatted as **comments** -- make sure everything in a code section is actually valid shell syntax; the point of a [mre] is so someone else can copy-and-paste with no changes to see the same behavior themselves and test proposed answers. In this case, that means `# => ...` instead of just `=> ...`

Comment: Also, `var= command ...` doesn't assign to var except transiently. You want `var=$(command ...)`; that's covered in [How do I set a variable to the output of a command in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651437/how-do-i-set-a-variable-to-the-output-of-a-command-in-bash). Which means that `echo "${tableName}"`, if anyone but you _actually ran_ your claimed/stated code, wouldn't actually work, since you aren't actually storing the output of awk in tableName.

Comment: BTW, `set -x` (aka `shopt -s xtrace`) is a good place to start to run things down.